# Beamer compilation error

Tags: beamer

I freshly installed Linux min 19.3, full texlive. Strangely enough, any beamer file produces tons of errors when compiled. For example, if I compile the following MWE

```
\documentclass[beamer,usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\title[]{\textbf{MWE}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

the first error messages are these:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.41 \newrobustcmd
                  *\only{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@only}{\beamer@@only}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.41 \newrobustcmd*
                   \only{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@only}{\beamer@@only}}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.41 \newrobustcmd*\only
                        {\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@only}{\beamer@@only}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Non-beamer tex files are OK so far.

Comment: I am able to compile your ```MWE``` with no errors. How are you compiling the document?

Comment: I suspect you have an earlier error saying that `etoolbox` is not available: can you check your log?

Comment: @JosephWright There is no mention of etoolbox in the log file.

Comment: @Tanvir Of course, it is supposed to compile. I could do it on my old Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: @Terry Comment the ```multimedia``` package and try to compile. Or create another beamer tex file and run ```pdflatex``` to see if you get the same error.

Comment: @Tanvir Neither helped. Same errors.

Comment: @Terry Could you post the entire error message in the question?

Comment: Please add the complete .log file so we can check package versions and if maybe an older locally installed package is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Compiling your MWE (with recent MiKTeX) mentioned errors can not be reproduced. You should have installed some older version of packages. Try to upgrade your LaTeX instalation.